# Accessible (and educational) deck building game for second grade primary school child?

Tags: deck-building

What deck building / card games would be most accessible to a 7-9 year old? As a bonus, are there any that could encourage his/her learning, in line with his/her abilities at that age?

As guidance, [Wikipedia states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_grade) that for second graders:

> ... students are taught place value to tens, hundreds or
>   thousands, and renaming with addition and subtraction... Another skill students practice is counting money and making change. Positive and negative numbers are introduced, but not added and subtracted.

Also

> In reading, students read to perform a task using fictional and
>   non-fictional texts, and learn about story elements, text features,
>   character traits, sequencing, and main idea/details.

As an example, my 7 year old is ready to move on from '[Top Trumps](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7262/top-trumps)'. He has a solid grasp of the relative values of numbers and in my opinion is ready to add a strategic element. We've tried and enjoyed '[King of Tokyo](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/70323/king-tokyo)', although I have noticed he mostly goes for the higher value cards'.

I'm sure there are many 'advanced/adult' games that 7-9 year olds are capable of getting their heads around, but I'd really like something that is immediately accessible to that age group.

Comment: Down-voters. Please provide reasons in comments.

Comment: You don't have any downvotes.  You do however have close votes, because this is a game recommendation question which are not allowed on the site.  See the FAQ page about "What kinds of questions should I ask".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simplicity, probably one of the easiest to learn would be [Star Realms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HRGMPIU). It's the simplest deck builder I've played, at least for the base game, but still provides some depth.

One other game I've seen lots of kids enjoy is [Quarriors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004U5RD1A). Your "deck" is composed of dice in a bag, but the same concept applies--you accumulate money to buy creature dice, and those creature dice deal damage to other creature dice. A lot of symbols to deal with, especially if you buy the expansions, but still very accessible.

Getting to math concepts of tens/hundreds and negatives might be difficult since deck builders tend to deal largely with single digit numbers and don't usually have "debt" systems or the like, but the money counting/addition/subtraction element should be present in almost any deck builder.